# Swift generics syntax

Tags: swift, generics, syntax

I have the following function:

```
func myFunc<T: MyProtocol>(param: ParamType, completion: @escaping (Result<T, NetworkError>) -> ())
```

Then I call it:

```
    myFunc(param) { response in
 }
```

I'm getting the "Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred", how I can set the T type in my calling?
Thanks.

Comment: You need to set the type explicitly `myFunc(param) { response: Result<YourType, NetworkError> in }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should be valid:

```
protocol MyProtocol { }

    struct ParamType { }
    class My: MyProtocol { }
    enum Result<T, E> {
        case result(T)
        case fail(E)
    }
    class NetworkError: Error { }
    func myFunc<T: MyProtocol>(param: ParamType, completion: @escaping (Result<T, NetworkError>) -> Void) { }

    myFunc(param: ParamType()) { (res: Result<My, NetworkError>) -> Void in
        print(res)
    }
```

Comment: I've tried (res: Result<My, NetworkError>) but forget '-> Void', i'm feeling stupid :) . Thanks.